# Who will peer review my edit on a post that's three years old?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, title, old-questions, too-minor

1. I suggested [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3212866) on three years old post. Who will peer review it?
2. Why can't I just change a `-s` to a `-u`? That's a pretty critical change despite not being 6 characters.
3. Why can't I ask a question that's about asking a question? Why can't I write "question" in the title?

Comment: You can see the peer review results of your suggested edit here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3212866

Comment: Urgh, that edit means my answer doesn't fit the bullet list items anymore. This is an OUTRAGE! (Actually no, I think I'll survive.)

Comment: Hilariously, none of the reviewers seem to understand the edit I made, and they rejected it. What do I do now? Weird that there seems to be no space for me to comment on my edit.

Answer (score 11):

1. The question will be added to the Suggested Edits review queue for anyone to review. It depends how many are currently in the queue to begin with, but it doesn't get assigned to any specific person, it just gets added to the list.
2. You can ask questions about questions here on Meta (that's one of the things Meta is for), but not on the main site. That site is for questions about development / programming.
3. You can't use the word Question in a title because it's already obvious it's a question - it's a Q&A site. Just like I wouldn't open my answer text by writing the word Answer; it's obvious so adding it would be just noise.